# обновление QTableView без записи в бд

Tags: c++, qt

Есть связка из `QSqlTableModel` и `QTableView`. В программе я работаю с моделью. И нужно чтобы после изменения модели изменения сразу же отображались в представлении, но без применения изменений в бд.
С добавлением или изменением проблем не возникает. Проблема возникает при удалении какой-либо строки. После вызова метода `removeRow()` значение в хедере меняется с индекса строки на `!` и ничего не происходит.

Answer (score 3):

Если я правильно понял, вас интересует [EditStrategy](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qsqltablemodel.html#EditStrategy-enum). А точнее `QSqlTableModel::OnManualSubmit`. Все изменения будет закешированы в модели, пока вы явно не вызовете метод `submitAll()` или `revertAll()`

```
QSqlTableModel *model = new QSqlTableModel(parent, database);
model->setEditStrategy(QSqlTableModel::OnManualSubmit);

//...

model->submitAll();
```

Comment: Не совсем, нужно чтобы эти закешированные изменения сразу отображались в QTableView

Comment: @sm4ll_3gg, а вы как данные в модели меняете? Через `setData`?

Comment: У меня проблема возникает при удалении. Когда я делаю `model->removeRow()` представление обновляется только после `submitAll()`

Comment: @sm4ll_3gg, увы, так было задумано разработчиками. [Вот](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4146633/row-deleted-from-model-stays-in-view-what-am-i-doing-wrong) аналогичный вопрос на англоязычном стэковерфлов.

Comment: Думаю вашу проблему можно решить при помощи `QSortFilterProxyModel`. Переопределить метод `filterAcceptsRow` и возвращать там [`!isDirty(index)`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qsqltablemodel.html#isDirty)